# Загрузка файла на сервер - баги, уязвимости

Tags: php, javascript, html, безопасность

На моем сайте есть форма для загрузки файла, в которой у пользователя есть возможность, написав комментарий, прикрепить файл. Загрузку файла я не контролирую: нет ограничения по размеру, по типу и т.п.

Что может злоумышленник сделать с такой загрузкой файла, где нет ни каких ограничений? 
Какие есть еще защиты кроме ограничения по размеру, типу?

Comment: Самый простой способ - загрузить скрипт, узнать адрес и выполнить его. А что в скрипте может быть - зависит лишь от фантазий кодера.

Comment: зачем далеко ходить) вот [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44610/) можно почитать, например, про опасные последствия бесконтрольной загрузки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Злоумышленник при заливке произвольного файла к вам на сервер в принципе может все что угодно. Файл может быть скриптом php или другим видом cgi и дать злоумышленнику полный доступ на ваш хостинг. А может быть каким нибудь скриптом/выполнимым файлом, который сработает в браузерах ваших пользователей.

Защита:

1. Проверять тип файла и не по расширению, а по внутреннему содержимому.
2. Если это картинки то в браузеры к пользователям они должны  попадать только в виде `<img>`
3. Скрипт загружающий файлы должен исключить наличие символов `/` и `..` в именах файлов. Что бы через него нельзя было залить файл в произвольную папку на сервере
4. Папка в которую заливаются файлы должна быть защищена от выполнения скриптов из нее. Для этого надо в `.htaccess` в этой папке (для apache) написать следующее:

   ```
   php_flag engine 0
   RemoveHandler .php
   AddType "text/html" .php .cgi .pl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .asp .jsp
   Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Самое опасное, что может произойти - ***удаленное выполнение кода***. Это означает, что злоумышленник может загрузить свой скрипт и запустить его. Что будет в скрипте зависит только от фантазии злоумышленника.

Я вижу два способа, как убрать данную уязвимость:

1. *Проверять загружаемый файл.* Если через Вашу форму будут загружать изображения, то необходимо проверить, является ли загружаемый файл изображением, и т.п.
2. *Убрать права на выполнение файлов.* Таким образом злоумышленник сможет спокойно просматривать изображения, но при этом у него не будет возможности выполнить, например, `php` скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один интересный вариант - это так называемая "Zip-бомба". Вкратце, идея такая: берём большой файл, который при архивации сильно уменьшается (например, 100500 миллиардов пробелов), архивируем файл, отправляем на сервер. Сервер разархивирует файл и умирает от того, что переполнен диск.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-бомба](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B0)